# Inheriting functions

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a `UITableViewCell` as well as a `UICollectionViewCell` that have almost the exact same functions in apart from a few details. I want to create a superclass that these two can inherit from, but can't figure out how to do it. I have done it for my `UITableViewController` and `UICollectionViewController` by using a `UIViewController` superclass. Each subclass is of type `UIViewController` with it's appropriate delegate/datasource methods. However, there are no datasource/delegate methods for `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the two implementations? "Apart from a few details" is pretty vague, and I'm curious as to how many details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject identical functionality into both class using a protocol plus a protocol extension:

```
@objc protocol MyProto {
    func someFunc()
}
extension MyProto {
    func someFunc() {
        print("howdy")
    }
}
class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell, MyProto {
}
class MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell, MyProto {
}
let cell1 = MyTableViewCell()
cell1.someFunc() // "howdy"
let cell2 = MyCollectionViewCell()
cell2.someFunc() // "howdy"
```

...showing that they both do the same thing, without repetition of the code.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll read up on protocol extensions. Do you think I should put the protocol and its extension into a new Swift file, for readability?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you put them. They have to be at top level of some swift file, that's all that matters.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering what the best practice for this kind of thing was from a readability point of view.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you think is readable! :) The advantage of putting a declaration in its own file is that you can name the file after the thing being declared, which can give you a hint where to look for the definition of that thing. On the other hand, one of the things I like about Swift is that I don't _have_ to do that; it's much easier to put multiple declarations in one file than it would have been in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any further protocol declarations for `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`.

Just create a base subclass from each respectively and implement the methods you need.

Then use them by creating subclasses from the base subclass

For example:

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet var foo : UILabel!

   var bar = false

   func method1() {}
   func method2() {}

}

class MySpecialTableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell { }
```